# Good examples of UK postcode lookup flow

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, postal-code

I'm looking for a good, well designed flow of a UK postcode lookup process as part of registration for an eCommerce account.

We're redesigning ours and want to see what is out there and how I can make it as friendly as possible.

--Update--

Basically our current design was a manual entry form (worked pretty well) which a less than experienced developer then bolted the postcode lookup onto.

So the order currently reads: Country, Line1, Line2, Line3, Town, County, Postcode. And he just put a lookup button on the bottom of that. So user goes line by line, THEN looks at postcode and uses the lookup.

I'd like to see some others in action because of the point made in the answers about allowing manual override.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either way, please make sure you include a manual address override (ie allow the user to enter their address without the aid of a look-up).  I live at a newly built address and it's not yet showing up on everyone's databases.  I'm unable to register with eCommerce sites about 50% of the time.  Very annoying.

:-)

Comment: Granted :) Thats kind of why I was asking the question!

Comment: Is there an look up API that returns the name of the building from input post code/ zip code? I am creating an app where I want to register a user only if he is living in a building with multiple apartments.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the simple house number\name and postcode prompt?

Perhaps you could say how your current lookup works and why it's felt to need redesign.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea - why not look at how the main PAF resellers do it on their websites - they wll have put more thought into it than most (you would think).

e.g. QAS, Postcodesoftware.co.uk, Hopewiser, even the Royal Mail themselves

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean asking:

1. House Name or Number:
2. Postcode:

Then a call to Capscan, Equifax (esp. if you will be doing a credit search later, as their address match is free in that case), the Post Office, or so on?

Then display to verify with the user (or display a list to select from).

All along with an option to manually enter their address - and in the background you should still attempt an address match on that so you get the unique address key.

Comment: No we're not doing anything credit or AVS related. I'm interested soley in the usability of entering a delivery address.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see; the nicest ones I have seen have a "sidebar" to the address where you could enter your postcode/number and press lookup; which would then fill in the address fields, which you could override as necessary.

In this way you have the normal address flow for manual entry and you don't end up putting postcode first.

Damned if I can find an example right now though!

Answer (score 0):

What I find to work well:

1. Country (defaults to UK)
2. Postcode + 'Find Address' Button
3. Postcode lookup result box/dropdown (shown only if button clicked)

Rest of form is hidden until address is selected, country changed to non UK or some error occurs (e.g. lookup server times out or postcode is not found)

1. Street (1 - 3 lines, best is 2)
2. Town

This makes things simple and works well is most of your visitors are from UK. For non UK visitors the 'Find Address' button should be hidden and for extra points you could move the postcode field below town.

An optional extra is to show a State/County field for non UK visitors too - in some countries this is an essential part of the addres. In the UK county is ignored by Royal Mail and should be left out of your form (shorter form, bettr usability).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

To do the lookup properly you have to use the Postal Address File (PAF) from the post office. It is expensive and there are restrictions on where you can use it - you can't include it in products.
But it does list the correct address for each house.

Comment: I know HOW technically to do the lookup - we already have a provider. Please read the question.

Comment: The others had already answered how - I was posting this for the archive/search since most develoeprs don't know about the PAF

Comment: That is not right either - there are several web based providers that will do it on a piece meal basis who are much more affordable.

Comment: -3 is a bit harsh.  Are we really so tough on people.  +1 for trying to be helpful.

Comment: @MartinBeckett Is there any look up API that returns the name of the building based on a post code/ zip code? I am creating an app where I want to register a user only if he is living in a building with multiple apartments.